# Converting ASP.NET Web Application to Website for Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I am using an ASP.NET **Web Application**, I want to change this application to **Website**.
 I was using **CrystalReportViewer**.

Is there any way to re-use the WebApp for Website, since I have another Website and I want to add Reports to that website.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually move your files into the web site without the .designer files.  As long as you copy over the .aspx and .aspx.cs files you should be fine.  You may need to re-add the CrystalReportViewer to the web page in order to get the new web site project to add the necessary references.

Comment: Thanks Justin! But the problem is that when I add a "ReportSelling.rpt" in website as a Crystal Report, I was able to see the "ReportSelling.rpt" but not the "ReportSelling.cs". As previously I was able to have "ReportSelling.cs" as well. What is the way to resolve this issue. Since I need to add code behind for this .rpt. Is there any other work-around for Website.

Comment: The "ReportSelling.cs" file is really the designer file for the Crystal Report inside the web application project.  For the website you can still set the report source for the viewer to the report file but access report properties differently.  To access properties like parameters, datasource, etc. you need to create a ReportDocument object with the source being your report file.

Comment: Thanks Justin! So that means, I have to create Properties to fetch values for each value? Isn't there any other easy/simple solution? It would be better if you send me any good tutorial link for this.

Comment: Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227452(v=vs.90).aspx for binding the non embedded report to the viewer.  Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227530(v=vs.90).aspx for other functionality examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to implement these links.